# QTabWidget move all tabs

Tags: c++, qt, qtabwidget

I want to change the position of all the tabs to the middle like the picture, how can i do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For static position you can use qss

```
QTabWidget::tab-bar {
    left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: how to use it, give example please.

Comment: @Zoro Allam In Qt Designer set it in property `styleSheet` of your `QTabWidget`. In code use `QTabWidget::setStyleSheet()`

Comment: i tried this but nothing happen tw->setStyleSheet("QTabWidget::tab-bar {left: 100px; };");

Comment: it worked in designer, but i want it to work with the code

Comment: @Zoro Allam What OS/Qt version/compiler you use? I have tested it on Windows 10, Qt 5.9, mingw

Comment: it worked, i think the problem i used vertcal tabs, i change left to top, thanks